# Vue JS: How to create a table in Vue js to retrive data from json api.

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Looking to Change a current  HTML view in Vue JS.
Format this current HTML view:
[image]
found in https://codepen.io/numerical/pen/JvWMMR

```
    data: {
    activePage: 0,
    baseUrl: 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch',
    chunkSize: 5,
    filters: ['change', 'changePercent', 'companyName','latestPrice',            'marketCap'],
    lastUpdated: false,
    quotes: [],
    refreshInterval: 60,
    symbols: [],
    transitioning: false,
    updateLoop: false
},
```

and make it like this table by getting/retrieving the json data. 
**Thanks in advance!** 
[image]
found in https://codepen.io/bertog/pen/EjmpXm

```
      <td>{{quotes}}</td>
      <td>{{symbols []}}</td>
```

Comment: what's your question or use case ?

Comment: Your table example https://boussadjra.github.io/vueye-table/  would work. Just don't know the values, that I have to use to retrieve data found in https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/batch?types=quote,news,chart&range=1m&last=10  If I take you table and use the Values in the json, where in your code would I use the Json values?

Comment: i used that json just for demo you could use any array that contains objects and you could also specify the fields to show using computed property

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim thank you!